# Append li to parent ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get text from an input to add to an existing ul in the parent using jquery, but when I do this:

```
$("input[type = 'text']").keypress(function(event){
    if(event.which === 13){
        //grabbing new todo from input
        var todoText = $(this).val();
        $(this).val("");
        //create a new li and add to ul
        $(this).parent().append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText + "</li>");
    }
});
```

it adds a new li directly to the parent. I realized I forgot to mention that I wanted it to be added to the existing ul, so I tried changing this:

```
//create a new li and add to ul
$(this).parent("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText + "</li>");
```

but it still didn't work, and now it doesn't even add anything anywhere. Maybe it's because I have the wrong syntax or something?

Here is an example of how my jade is structured:

```
.frame
    .bit-2
      h1
        | text 
        i.fa.fa-plus             
      input(type='text', placeholder='text')           
      ul
        li
          span
            i.fa.fa-trash
          |  text              
        li
          span
            i.fa.fa-trash
          |  text
```

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Have you looked at the modified HTML in the Dev tools of your browser?  It is possible that the text is being added, but just not where you think it is.  Also, if there is an error in your Javascript, that will notify you of the problem.

Comment: input don't have parent ul, use siblings...

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the modified html. That's how I figured out it wasn't adding to the ul. I'm also not getting any errors.

Comment: Can you please share your HTML code as well.

Comment: @Ivan Karaman How do I do that? Because I still need to be able to include  the parent since there are three other inputs and I don't know which one will be entered.

Comment: You should select the *ul* element by `$('ul').append...` and not by `$(this).parent('ul')`

Comment: @Rahul Patel Do you want me to convert the jade above into html?

Comment: @Mario Alexandro Santini I still need the parent because otherwise it will add to my three other inputs as well.

Comment: create please jsfiddle, it will faster...

Comment: @ShristiSharma in the append you just add *li* elements to a *ul* element, why you say it add an *input* too? If you have more details you haven't share, please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use .next() function like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type = 'text']").keypress(function(event){

    if(event.which === 13){
      //grabbing new todo from input
      var todoText = $(this).val();
      $(this).val("");
      //create a new li and add to ul
      $(this).next("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText + "</li>");
    }
  });
});
```

For demo please check below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type = 'text']").keypress(function(event){
    
    if(event.which === 13){
      //grabbing new todo from input
      var todoText = $(this).val();
      $(this).val("");
      //create a new li and add to ul
      $(this).next("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText + "</li>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
<ul><li>First</li></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

First of, if you don't want the direct parent, but *a* parent, you should use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

```
$(this).closest('ul')
```

Secondly, in the structure, you've posted, the UL doesn't appear to be a parent of the input, but rather a sibling, meaning you can select it with [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(this).next('ul')
```

This, however, is pretty specific and means the input will always have to be right next to the ul.
If you know it will always be in context of the frame, I would probably go with something like:

```
$(this).closest('.frame').find('ul')
```

Answer (score -1):

May be this will works

```
$(this).closest("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span> " + todoText + "</li>");
```

Comment: Ul is not parent of the textbox so this will not append to UL.

Comment: sorry.. i didn't see the structure(careless)@RahulPatel